# Show/hide content on click, by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm used to working with Wordpress, however I'm using a different platform (Squarespace)in this case. I need to be able to show content on click, for the blog section of this website.

Example: in the news page, I have a list of news items, with an excerpt for each article. On click, I want to show the content instead of excerpt.

The problem I am having is if I click, it shows all the content from all the posts, not only the one I clicked on.

the process i did is on my blog list page I have display each 'post excerpt' and the full content, i make the full content hidden and appear with lightbox.

This is what I've done so far, but it doesnt work, nothing happens:

The tag `{id}` give as a class the path - it displays fine in the source code.

Does anybody have any advise ?

so far my code is like ( to display the list):

`

```
 <article class="entry cf {@|item-classes}" id="article-{id}" data-item-id="{id}">
 {.main-image?}
<div class="main-image-wrapper">
  <a href="{fullUrl}"><div class="main-image content-fill"><img {@|image-meta} /></div></a>
</div>
{.end}


  <div class="entry-meta">
                {.section categories}<div><em>{.equal? collection.typeName "products"}Found{.or}{.end} </em> {.repeated section @}<a href="{collection.fullUrl}?category={@|url-encode}" rel="tag">{@}</a>{.alternates with}, {.end}</div>{.end}
                {.if categories && tags} <em></em> {.end}

              </div>
<div id="all-content">

<div class="entry-title-wrapper">
  <h1 data-content-field="title" class="entry-title">
  {.passthrough?}
    <a href="{sourceUrl}" class="entry-title-passthrough" target="_blank">{title}</a>
  {.or}
   <p class="date">
    <time class="published" datetime="{addedOn|date %F}">{addedOn|date %B %e, %Y}</time>
  </p>
    <a href="{fullUrl}">{title}</a>
  {.end}
  </h1>

</div>

</div>

<div class="entry-content">

  {.excerpt?}
    {excerpt}
  {.or}
    {.section body}
        {@}
      {.end}
    {.end}
    <p class="entry-actions-simple">
      {.comments?}
        <a class="entry-comments" href="{fullUrl}#comments-outer-wrapper" title="Comments">
        {.if websiteSettings.disqusShortname}
        {@|comment-link}
        {.or}
        {.section publicCommentCount}
        {@} Comment{@|pluralize}
        {.or}
          Comment
        {.end}
      {.end}
      </a>
    {.end}
    {@|like-button}{@|social-button-inline}
  </p>
     <header class="entry-header cf">

  <p class="entry-actions">
    {.comments?}
      <a class="entry-comments" href="{fullUrl}#comments-outer-wrapper" title="Comments">
      {.if websiteSettings.disqusShortname}
        {@|comment-link}
      {.or}
      {.section publicCommentCount}
        {@} Comment{@|pluralize}
        {.or}
          Comment
        {.end}
      {.end}
      </a>
    {.end}
  </p>

  <p class="entry-more-link"><a class="more" href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1 {id}"></a></p>
```

`

and to display the content:

```
<div style='display:none'>
  <div class="lightbox" id="fl1">

 <div class="main-image-wrapper">
<img style="width:100%" {@|image-meta} />
  </div>


    <div class="entry-meta">
                {.section categories}<div><em>{.equal? collection.typeName "products"}Found{.or}{.end} </em> {.repeated section @}<a href="{collection.fullUrl}?category={@|url-encode}" rel="tag">{@}</a>{.alternates with}, {.end}</div>{.end}
                {.if categories && tags} <em></em> {.end}

              </div>
<div id="all-content">

<div class="entry-title-wrapper">
  <h1 data-content-field="title" class="entry-title">
  {.passthrough?}
    <a href="{sourceUrl}" class="entry-title-passthrough" target="_blank">{title}</a>
  {.or}
   <p class="date">
    <time class="published" datetime="{addedOn|date %F}">{addedOn|date %B %e, %Y}</time>
  </p>
    <a class="lightbox" href="{fullUrl}">{title}</a>
  {.end}
  </h1>

</div>

</div>

<div class="entry-content lightbox">

  {.excerpt?}
    {excerpt}
   <span style="font-size:16px">        {.section body}
</span> 


      {@}
    {.end}
  {.end}
  <p class="entry-actions-simple">
    {.comments?}
      <a class="entry-comments" href="{fullUrl}#comments-outer-wrapper" title="Comments">
      {.if websiteSettings.disqusShortname}
        {@|comment-link}
      {.or}
      {.section publicCommentCount}
        {@} Comment{@|pluralize}
        {.or}
          Comment
        {.end}
      {.end}
      </a>
    {.end}
      {@|like-button}{@|social-button-inline}
     </p>
<header class="entry-header cf lightbox">

         {@|like-button}{@|social-button-inline}

 <div class="tag" style="float:right">
 {.section tags}<div><em><img style="width:20px;padding-right:10px" src="https://four23main.squarespace.com/assets/images/tag.png"></em> {.repeated section @}<a href="{collection.fullUrl}?tag={@|url-encode}" rel="tag">{@}</a>{.alternates with}, {.end}</div>{.end}
                {.passthrough?}
                {.or}
                {.section sourceUrl}<div class="source-url"><a href="{sourceUrl}" target="_blank">Source</a></div>{.end}
                {.end}
                </dv>
</header>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the HTML for the button being clicked and the item being shown?

Comment: thank you, I have edit my code and questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go for something like

```
$('#mainArticle').click(function () {
    if ($('#mainArticle').hasClass("expanded")) {
        $('#mainArticle').css("height", "40px");
        $('#mainArticle p:first-child').css("width", "12em");
        $('#mainArticle p:first-child').css("white-space", "nowrap");
        $('#mainArticle').removeClass("expanded");
    } else {
        $('#mainArticle').css("height", "100%");
        $('#mainArticle p:first-child').css("width", "100%");
        $('#mainArticle p:first-child').css("white-space", "normal");
        $('#mainArticle').addClass("expanded");
    }
});
```

Here it is in practice http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/tgdn64jx/